# find the first number in the last line of text file and put ino integer variable visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am making a program that creates a text file that formats like so:

[1, * John, Doe, Family, 0002354561]

[2, * Jason, Doe, Obstetric, 0002358411]

[3, * Mikael, Doe, Pediatric, 0002352361]

[4, * Jamiel, Doe, Orthopedic, 0002354547]

What I need is a way to read the file and get the first number of the last line. and then put that into an integer.

I know i can read the first line like this:

```
    Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    fileReader =
    My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(("..\..\..\Patients.txt"))

    Dim stringReader As String
    stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
    MsgBox("The first line of the file is " & stringReader)
```

But how do i read the last line and get the second char into an integer variable?

Comment: Why not split the string on the comma and use the last element to get the first char which is your first number, which from the looks of it is always 0 unless you want the whole number which would be the last element of the array returned from the split - and if that bracket is a part of the string use replace to remove the bracket.

Comment: It wont always be zero. that is just a placeholder for phone numbers. And I have no idea how to manipulate the string the way you speak, at least not in visual basic.

Comment: Why are you putting it in a format that makes it more difficult for you to retrieve later?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like this

```
Dim lastLine As String = File.ReadLines(myFileName) _
                                .Where(Function(f As String) (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(f))).Last.ToString
Dim startpos As Integer = lastLine.IndexOf(",", 3)
lastline = Substring(lastline, startpos).Trim
Dim firstchar as String = Substring(lastline,0,1)
Dim result As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(firstchar, result) Then Return result _
        Else Return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could accomplish the task, this puts all the numbers into an arraylist.  Not that by converting it to an long(or integer) it will remove any leading zeros

```
Public Function GetDigits() As System.Collections.ArrayList
    Dim numList As System.Collections.ArrayList
    numList = New System.Collections.ArrayList()
    Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(("C:\Patients.txt"))

    Dim stringReader As String
    While Not fileReader.EndOfStream
        stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
        If Trim(stringReader) = "" Then Continue While
        Dim strParts
        strParts = Split(stringReader, Chr(44))
        Try
            numList.Add(Integer.Parse(Trim(Replace(strParts(UBound(strParts)), "]", ""))))
        Catch
            MsgBox("Could not parse string: " & stringReader)
        End Try
    End While
    fileReader.Close()
    GetDigits = numList
End Function
```